# A single metric to quantify improvement in success rate

Tags: statistics

Is there a standard or common metric used to describe how much a success rate has improved?

If a success rate has changed from $x$ to $y$, then we might report "improvement" additively as $(y-x)$, multiplicatively as $\frac{y}{x}$, or measuring the multiplicative reduction of failure rate as $\frac{1-x}{1-y}$.

But none of these metrics individually captures all scenarios. For example:

- If the success rate improved from 45% to 55%, the additive improvement of $+10\%$ seems reasonable to use. Depending on the domain, a $+10\%$ improvement could certainly be seen as *impressive*.
- If the success rate improved from 0.1% to 1%, this is an *impressive* $10\times$ multiplicative improvement in success rate, but additively the 0.9% improvement is small.
- If the success rate improved from 99% to 99.9%, the additive and multiplicative improvements are small, but we have $10\times$ fewer failures which is also an *impressive* result.

Is there some other metric for success rate improvement that tracks more accurately with the various interpretations of "*impressive*" as exemplified above? Of course no metric will be perfect in all scenarios, but is there any **more standard, common, or principled** metric?

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to have a single metric to track all situations and cost functions.

If you had multiple criteria, say $f_i(x,y),$ each one of which is relevant for some scenario, say the $i^{th}$ scenario, and each scenario had relative importance that could be measured by some coefficient $\alpha_i,$ so that increasing the coefficient implies increasing the importance of the relevant criterion, an obvious metric to use would be
$$
\sum_{i} \alpha_i f_i(x,y), \quad \sum_i \alpha_i=1,\quad \alpha_i\geq 0,
$$
which has nice properties especially if the

Comment: Yes, I'm aware one could naively do a linear combination of the metrics I suggested. I'm asking whether there is any more standard, more common, or more principled approach than a simple average or with alpha coefficients pulled out of thin air.

Comment: fair enough, it was unclear from the question.